# designing a game c++

Tags: c++, winapi

ok im gonna be using directx maybe 9.  I have designed two other games they were too simple im asking how game is designed like they make one file that includes menu codes and the all level codes.........
thanks

Comment: I always found http://nehe.gamedev.net/ a good source of info, but it's for OpenGL

Comment: Stack Overflow works best when you ask a specific question. This is far too vague.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try checking out the Official Microsoft site:

```
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/aa937791.aspx
```

Or, you can check out this site, designed for beginners:

```
http://www.gamedev.net/reference/start_here/
```